# How to not exit and wait for new log messages when running gcloud logging read?

Tags: gcloud

we are using [gcloud logging read](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read) to read messages from a Cloud Run service. The command works but it exits once it reaches the end of file. How can we tell it to not exit and wait for new messages to appear in the log? similar to how  `tail -f` works:

> -f      The -f option causes tail to not stop when end of file is reached, but rather to wait for additional data to be appended to the input.  The -f option is ignored if the standard input is a pipe, but not if it is a FIFO.

Comment: [streaming and live tailing log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/streaming-live-tailing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command:

```
gcloud beta logging tail
```

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/logging/tail)

To enable this feature:

[Live tailing log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#live-tailing)

Comment: Great. Thanks! I couldn't find it when I searched.